# Give up versus give in

Tags: meaning, differences

Pardon if this has been asked and answered already here, I couldn't find it by myself.

What is the difference between giving in and giving up? I know one means that you're giving up/in and letting someone else do it, other has no continuous actions.

Could someone explain this, please?

Comment: give in always has a receiver of the action, even if it is implied. He gave in to hunger and died, versus He gave up and surrendered to the enemy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both have a similar meaning of *surrender*. However, generally speaking, *give up* implies a failed attempt to do something:

> "[[**Give up**]? In our moment of triumph?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRY0cs26Zvo) I think you overestimate their chances."
>
> He refused to **give up**, believing that success was just around the corner.

while *give in* implies a change of heart after *insistence* or *pleading*:

> After days of begging, Amin finally **gave in** and let his daughter have some of the Halloween candy.
>
> Cindy couldn't believe that Mark **gave in** to his boss's demand to work on Saturdays.